# Употребима ли данная словесная конструкция?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Почему было не сделать** этого на рассвете, как того требует доктрина?
Эквавалент:
Почему вы не сделали этого на рассвете, как того требует доктрина?

Это перевод, в оригинале уточнения тех к кому обращаются(вы из эквивалента) нет, так как это ясно из предыдущего предложения(что верно и для моего перевода).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Почему было не сделать** - подобные выражения встречаются часто, например:

Зачем использовать свой отпуск, **почему было не дождаться** официального направления?

Но **почему было не сказать** нам правду?

А **почему было не спросить** об этом прямо?

Другое дело - **как определить грамматику такого оборота?**. Попробуем сравнить: надо было так сделать - почему (надо) было так не сделать. Тогда это вариант составного глагольного сказуемого, модальная  связка в форме прошедшего времени (объяснение в качестве гипотезы).

Answer (score 0):

Да, такая конструкция употребима, но (в отличие от вашего эквивалента, где всё хорошо) "это" стилистически лучше употребить в винительном, а не родительном падеже: условно говоря, это позитивное предложение "сделать *это* вчера" (оно по форме и для будущего такое же), а не предложение "не делать *этого*".

Тем не менее, выбирайте тот вариант, который вам кажется более "русским" для контекстной ситуации: в переводе важнее передать смысл, чем сохранить похожую грамматическую конструкцию. Если смысл тот же, представьте себе, какими словами выразил бы его русский персонаж или рассказчик.

Comment: ---стилистически лучше употребить в винительном, а не родительном падеже
+Есть какие ни буть объективные причины, или всё упирается в субъективную приятность для ушей(которая для меня лично одинакова, поскольку я много где употреблял такую конструкцию)
---Если смысл тот же, представьте себе, какими словами выразил бы его русский персонаж или рассказчик.
+А вот тут не согласен, так можно доадаптировать до полной лажи.